# Malloc and strdup(self implementation) in assembly

Tags: c, pointers, assembly

**Update: Fixed my C code example. I'm copying from a char* to another char* in assembly. I need to copy by value and then return the address of the new char* to the caller.**

I'm trying to create an equivalent of the following C code in assembly but gdb/valgrind is reporting that I'm attempting to free something that is already "freed".

Code in C:

```
char* func( int x, char* name){

    namestr = (char *) malloc( strlen(name) + 1 );
    nameestr = strdup( namestr, strlen(name) +1 );
    free( name ); //Just showing what I plan to do later.

    return namestr;    
}

int main( ){
    char* name = (char *) malloc( 10 );
    *name = "0123456789"

    char* some_string = func( 10, name );
    free( some_string );
}
```

Code in Assembly:

```
new_student:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %edi
    pushl   %esi
    subl    $20, %esp
    movl    12(%ebp), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, %edi
    movl    %ecx, -12(%ebp)

;get length and allocate the appropriate space
.STR_ALLOCATE:
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    $-1, %ecx
    repnz   scasb
    notl    %ecx
    subl    $1, %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
    movl    %ecx, -8(%ebp)
    pushl   %ecx
    call    allocate
    add     $4, %esp
    movl    %eax, -16(%ebp)

;copy the string byte by byte
.STR_CPY:
    movl    -8(%ebp), %ecx
    movl    %eax, %edi
    movl    12(%ebp), %esi
    rep     movsb
    movl    -12(%ebp), %eax

.END:
    popl    %esi
    popl    %edi
    leave
    ret
```

Can anyone give me some hints on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Er, I don't get what you're trying to imply here. I aware that i'm using pointers. Edit: Damn, got it.

Comment: Your C code is wrong: free(name) tries to free the string that was not allocated with malloc. If you get the same error in Assembly, your Assembly copy is really good...

Comment: I think it should be strcpy and not strdup, typo ?

Comment: @AlexFarber I fixed that part of the C Code, I'm in fact trying to free something allocated by malloc in the full code. mux I'm trying to do strdup, I want to copy by value to a new char* and return the address of the char* so I can do anything with the old char* and not affect the new one.

Comment: you're calling strdup with the wrong args,it takes a string and an optional number of bytes and returns a new string, read the man page please. However, if you change it to strcpy, the call will be correct and it will have the same effect

Comment: @mux Ok, thanks for your comment but I'm really trying to work with the assembly part of the code. Fixing my C code doesn't really fix my assembly code. It's there to show what I'm trying to do.

Comment: yup just realised that after commenting :) but it's better to fix the C code anyway, to avoid confusion...

Comment: I'm a little curious about the intent of the `subl $1, %eax; addl $1, %eax` sequence of instructions after the `repnz scasb` that calculates the string length.

Comment: Are you really using the C runtime function `free()` to deallocate memory that was allocated by your own `allocate` function?  The only way that will work (in general) is if the `allocate` function is just a wrapper around `malloc()`/`calloc()`.

Comment: If you can't write the C correctly, take it out. It's completely wrong and only confuses things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your assembly routine you load the return value into `eax`:

```
movl    -12(%ebp), %eax
```

However, `-12(%ebp)` contains the pointer that was passed in to the function, not the one that was allocated. You should instead do the following just before returning:

```
movl    -16(%ebp), %eax
```

(Or just don't do anything - nothing seems to modify `eax` after the return from the `call allocate` instruction).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It is exactly what I needed, something to push me to look in the right direction. Just to clarify on your comments, I've no idea why I added the subl $1, %eax in the first place. Next, allocate() is a wrapper around malloc() with some additional functionality, but it works exactly like malloc.

Answer (score 0):

In your c code You have written

```
free(name)
```

which is might be causing you a problem as you can't free the memory which is not allocated either by malloc , calloc or realloc
and also namestr is not visible in main which you are trying to free because it's in the stack of func function

Comment: namestr is local to func() only

Comment: Fixed my C code, I always seem to have mistakes when trying to do something like this (write C code to represent what I'm doing in assembly).